# NextJS 13 disable saving page during navigation

Tags: next.js, next.js13

NextJS 13, app directory.
I have a card page where I can add a card to my favorites, and there is also a page with all my favorite cards. These pages are server components. The transition to the favorites page takes place using the Link component, and from this page back - using a button in the browser that moves back through the history. The problem is that Next js saves the favorites page, and if you return to the cards page from this page, add another card to favorites and return to the favorites page, the page will not be updated and the data on it too. I need the favorites page to either not be saved or updated when I visit.

I understand that it is possible to use client components and useEffect in them to update data in this way, but this does not seem to me the best way. I want to understand if there is a more beautiful way.